# How to connect an Alexa skill to Google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I am a student and I have a spreadsheet which has all of my upcoming assignments. I know that skills can connect to an API, is there any way I can get Alexa to read the last line from my Google sheet?

Comment: This is really vague. The most straightforward answer is you build a Google Sheets API client into your skill, use it to query your sheet, and then provide that response. But it seems you're looking for something prepackaged.

Comment: To be honest. i haven't tried it yet, but this is new info as i didn't know google had an API for their sheets. ill give it a go. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api) has Node.js support, which is a common language to write Alexa Skill handler functions in. So what one could do is write a skill in Node.js [hosted on AWS Lambda](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-an-aws-lambda-function.html) that performed the necessary calls to Google Sheets to retrieve what you need. It's a bit of work, but not extreme and would be a great learning opportunity.

Look around and you might even find some Alexa Skill projects that already do things similar to this.